# string comparison with [ ] fails

Tags: shell-script, test

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Enter any string"
read string
string1 = $(echo $string | rev)
if ["$string" == "$string1"]
then
     echo "String is palindrome"
else
     echo "String is not Palindrome"
fi
```

I am trying to check whether a string is a palindrome or not. Below is the error I get:

```
# ./palindrome.sh
Enter any string
mom
./palindrome.sh: line 5: string1: command not found
./palindrome.sh: line 6: [mom: command not found
String is not Palindrome
```

Comment: There may be a better duplicate, but there's at least https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/117438/117549 (linked to from https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/562423/getting-a-01-command-not-found-error-at-the-if-statement-line)

Comment: @Inian I did that change but it says string1: command not found

Comment: @JeffSchaller Go to the [tag:test] tag wiki to find a likely duplicate

Comment: @AdilAli: Also `string1=$(echo "$string" | rev)` no spaces

Comment: `string1 = $(` => `string1=$(`